# Python error: ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python

Self studying python and experimenting with reading and writing files.

I'm building a single-user cash tracker with a log that outputs the total amount to a .txt file.

I am writing an initial value of "0" to the .txt file as a string instead of an int, otherwise I throw an error.

When I go to call a function that floats the "0" I get a 
  File "atm.py", line 75, in checkBalance
    floatCurrent = float(current)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

```
def addStartingBalance():
    print("\n\nShall I add a starting balance to your new account?")
    addStart = str(input())
    addStart = addStart.lower()
    if addStart == "n" or addStart == "no":
        file = open("Bank Data.txt", "w")
        file.write(str("0"))
```

and the function that is throwing an error...

```
def checkBalance():
    file = open("Bank Data.txt", "r")
    print("Your current balance is: " +(file.read()))
    current = open("Bank Data.txt", "r").read()
    floatCurrent = float(current)
    file.close()
```

Question is, is there a way around writing a string to a .txt? Why can't I write an integer to a .txt file?

Answer (score 0):

In order to write an integer to a .txt file, the integer must have been converted to a string, first:

```py
file = open("filename.txt", "w")
integer = 0
file.write(str(integer))
```

Comment: Note: You're welcome to also delete questions if you post them in mistake

Comment: I've made some changes to your answer. If you feel uncomfortable with these changes, you can edit and rollback the edit. But feel free to also delete the question as already mentioned or mark this answer as the solution to avoid more (unqualified) answers and more work from others here.